# Access MySql array by column name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My query looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE btn_group_id = 1`;

Also I have array of languages `$langs = array(5,7,19)` the same in `btn_lang_id`

```
$btn = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [btn_id] => 1
            [btn_group_id] => 1
            [btn_lang_id] => 5
            [btn_text] => aaa1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [btn_id] => 2
            [btn_group_id] => 1
            [btn_lang_id] => 7
            [btn_text] => bbb2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [btn_id] => 3
            [btn_group_id] => 1
            [btn_lang_id] => 19
            [btn_text] => ccc3
        )
)
```

My question is how I can use this array to `echo` data by using `btn_lang_id`

```
foreach ($langs as $lang){
echo $btn[$lang['lang_id']]['btn_text'];
}
```

I want the above 3 arrays of `$btn` accessed by language id not by index 0,1,2. I there any way?

Comment: You can store the array serialized or in json format, and then retrieve it from the DB and unserialize or json decode. That way you can store the data and preserve the array structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with the "btn_lang_id" as a key using the following code:

```
<?php
$langs = array(5,7,19);

$btn = array(
    '0' => array(
            'btn_id' => 1,
            'btn_group_id' => 1,
            'btn_lang_id' => 5,
            'btn_text' => 'aaa1',
        ),
    '1' => array(
            'btn_id' => 2,
            'btn_group_id' => 1,
            'btn_lang_id' => 7,
            'btn_text' => 'bbb2',
        ),
    '2' => array(
            'btn_id' => 3,
            'btn_group_id' => 1,
            'btn_lang_id' => 19,
            'btn_text' => 'ccc3',
        ),
);

$customArr = array();   
foreach($langs as $key=>$value){
  $customArr[$value] = $btn[$key];
}
print_R($customArr);
?>
```